# Why does $\operatorname E(\varepsilon\mid x) = 0 \implies \operatorname{cov}(\varepsilon,x) = 0$?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, covariance, conditional-expectation

I understand the intuition behind the question but I'm trying to prove it to myself with math.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon \mid X) = 0$, the [law of iterated expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) gives $\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon \mid X)) = \mathbb{E}(0) = 0$.  This reduces the covariance equation to:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{Cov}(\varepsilon, X) 
= \mathbb{E}(\varepsilon X) - \mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(\varepsilon) 
= \mathbb{E}(\varepsilon X). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Now we use the [law of iterated expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) again to get:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{Cov}(\varepsilon, X) 
&= \mathbb{E}(\varepsilon X) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon X \mid X)) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(X \cdot \mathbb{E}(\varepsilon \mid X)) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(X \cdot 0) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(0) = 0. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$